# PHP if and else statement

Tags: php, user-input

I have a form that shows users results based on location.

When the page loads, the PHP shows the results based on the userIP location which comes from my geoIP script which works fine. This ip location gets stored in the `$location` variable.

But, What I also want is to allow the user to change this location based on what zip code he provides in the input text field and then clicks submit.

**Here is my PHP:**

```
$geo = geoCheckIP($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

if (isset($geo) && ($geo != "not found, not found")) {
    $location = $geo;
}
    else
    {
    $location = (isset($_POST['location'])    ? $_POST['location']    : '');
}
```

**The form:**

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
<div class="postal"><input name="location" id="postal" type="text" value="<?php echo $location; ?>" placeholder="Postal Code or City, State"></div><div id="example">ex.: San Francisco, CA</div><div class="search"><input name="search" id="search" type="submit" value="Search"></div>
</form>
```

Then below the form is where the xml is loaded, where `&l=".$location."` is where the zip code gets inserted.

**xml:**

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url."publisher=".$publisher."&q=".$q."&l=".$location."&sort=".$sort."&radius=".$radius."&st=".$st."&jt=".$jt."&start=".$start."&limit=".$limit."&fromage=".$fromage."&highlight=".$highlight."&filter=".$filter."&latlong=".$latlong."&co=".$co."&chnl=".$chnl."&userip=".$userip."&useragent=".$useragent."&v=".$v);
```

So everything works except for when the if statement is fired. If a zip code is entered into the input field, it just reverts back to the user based IP Location.

But if the User based IP location is not set or `"not found, not found"` then the else statement fires. In that case the user is able to enter a zip code, click submit and see results based on the zip code entered.

How can I rearrange my php code to allow both options?

If the IP location is available, I still want the page to initially load with those results, while giving the user the ability to enter zip code and see results based on what zip code he provides after clicking submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to rearrange based on what should logically be tested first:

```
$location = ''; // assume the worst
if (isset($_POST['location'])) {
    // location given, use that
    $location = $_POST['location'];
} else {
    // location not given, find it based on IP address if possible
    $geo = geoCheckIP($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

    if (isset($geo) && ($geo != "not found, not found")) {
        $location = $geo;
    }
}
```

Comment: your answer works fine too. So which code is slightly better? @Rakesh Sharma or Jack?

Comment: @Mike Actually, I noticed a slight logic bug in my answer, which I've updated; the difference between our answers is where the fallback value gets defined, at the top or in the `else` clause.

Comment: Your updated code works fine too without any php errors or notices in my error log. So, what is the difference between your code and @rakesh-sharma ?

Comment: @Mike The only difference is that my code doesn't check whether the given location by the user is non-empty, that is, is not an empty string; changing the condition to `isset($_POST['location']) && strlen($_POST['location'])` makes it the same thing.

Comment: I see. How would you change your above code to include sessions? So that the value in the input field will be saved when user reloads or goes to another page. Whatever they enter in there will stay there until they manually change it to something else.

Comment: @Mike Then, the second condition becomes `} elseif (isset($_SESSION['location'])) { ... }`, you get the idea.

Comment: @Mike That code seems fine to me. Do make sure to store the value of `$geo` or `$_POST['location']` inside the session, too. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E8Bb6/1/).

Comment: Thanks for adjusting it. Works perfect now. The way it was before, when I'd go to another page, it would always revert back to the geoIP instead of what I had entered into the search field. How do I extend the session? When I click the back button I get `Webpage has expired`.

Comment: @Mike If something is posted (and it's not an ajax request), you should perform a redirect afterwards to prevent that browser behaviour.

Comment: where would I redirect to? The page does not change to another url when the form is posted. It stays on the current url and just loads the new content on the same page.

Comment: @Mike Just redirect to yourself; I know that sounds rather dumb, but that's how life is sometimes :)

Comment: you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/25hB4/ I don't think I get it. The form post is already posting to the url that it resides on. If I try to redirect it will cause a loop?

Comment: You should *only* redirect if `$_POST['location']` was given.

Comment: If you have the time, I'm trying to figure out pagination. It's pretty much the last thing I need to tackle. I posted it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442662/pagination-on-the-api-indeed-com-xml-feed-25-results-per-page-how-to-paginate/

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if (isset($_POST['location']) && !empty($_POST['location'])) {
    $location = $_POST['location'];
} 
else {
    $geo = geoCheckIP($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
     $location = (!empty($geo) && $geo != "not found, not found" ? $geo : '');
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between your code and Jack's? Both work fine.