# Pagination on the API Indeed.com xml feed 25 results per page, How to Paginate?

Tags: php, xml, pagination

I have set up the Indeed.com xml feed on my site. Their API only allows 25 results per query. How can I paginate the results if there are more than 25?

I have not found a satisfactory or thorough enough answer anywhere online. I've searched for weeks on this.

Here is what I have in my code:

**PHP:**

```
        // Indeed.com API URL parameters
    $url = 'http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch'.'?';
    $publisher = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $q = $query;

    $location = '';
    if (isset($_POST['location'])) {
        $location = $_POST['location'];
    } else {
        $geo = geoCheckIP($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        if (isset($geo) && ($geo != "not found, not found")) {
            $location = $geo;
        }
    }
    $sort = 'date';
    $radius = '20';
    $st = '';
    $jt = '';
    $start = '0';
    $limit = '25';
    $fromage = '';
    $highlight = '0';
    $filter = '1';
    $latlong = '0';
    $co = 'us';
    $chnl = '';
    $userip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $useragent = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) : 'unknown';
    $v = '2';
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url."publisher=".$publisher."&q=".$q."&l=".$location."&sort=".$sort."&radius=".$radius."&st=".$st."&jt=".$jt."&start=".$start."&limit=".$limit."&fromage=".$fromage."&highlight=".$highlight."&filter=".$filter."&latlong=".$latlong."&co=".$co."&chnl=".$chnl."&userip=".$userip."&useragent=".$useragent."&v=".$v);
```

**HTML BODY**

```
    <div class="paradiv">
      <h1><?php echo $xml->totalresults . " " . $jobroll_title . " Near " . $location ?></h1>
      <!-- BEGIN INDEED ORDERED LIST-->
      <ol class="jobs">
        <?php

    foreach($xml->results->result as $result) { ?>
        <li class="job <?php echo (++$liBgColor%2 ? 'odd' : 'even'); ?>">
          <div class="title_wrapper">
            <div id="jobtitle"><strong><a onmousedown="<?php echo $result->onmousedown;?>" rel="nofollow" href="<?php echo $result->url;?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $result->jobtitle;?></a></strong></div>
            <div id="company"><?php echo $result->company;?></div>
          </div>
          <div id="snippet">
            <?php $result->snippet = str_replace("  ", ". ", $result->snippet); echo $result->snippet;?>
          </div>
          <div id="location"><strong>Location:</strong> <?php echo $result->formattedLocationFull;?></div>
          <div id="date"><span class="posted <?php echo (++$locationBgColor%2 ? 'even' : 'odd'); ?>">Posted <?php echo $result->formattedRelativeTime;?></span></div>
          <div id="details-2"><strong><a onmousedown="<?php echo $result->onmousedown;?>" rel="nofollow" href="<?php echo $result->url;?>" target="_blank">Details</a></strong></div>
        </li>
        <?php } ?>
      </ol>
      <!-- END INDEED ORDERED LIST -->

      <!-- THIS IS WHERE THE PAGINATION WILL DISPLAY -->
      <div class="pagenumber"><?php echo "Page Number " . "<a href=\"" . (rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/')) . "\">" . $xml->pageNumber . "</a>" ?></div>
    </div>
```

This is how it works. A user arrives on the web page, then the page loads with the job results based on the users location. If less than 25 results are found for their zip code then there is no problem and pagination isn't needed.

But if the xml feed has more than 25 results, it will show 25 and that's it. If I want to display the rest, I have to paginate. This is what I need help with.

Here is how their API url works.

```
http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&q=java&l=austin%2C+tx&sort=&radius=&st=&jt=&start=0&limit=25&fromage=&filter=&latlong=1&co=us&chnl=&userip=1.2.3.4&useragent=Mozilla/%2F4.0%28Firefox%29&v=2
```

The part that says `&start=0&limit=25` is how to display the results based on page number of the xml.

So for example: `&start=0&limit=25` would be page 0 showing 25 results, `&start=25&limit=25` would be page 1 showing the next 25 results and `&start=50&limit=25` would be page 2 showing the remaining 25 results. This example is based on if there are a total of 75 results in the xml feed.

And in my `// Indeed.com API URL parameters` above I have it set to start on page 0 and limit to 25. They do not allow beyond 25 in limit. If set higher it will default to 25.

```
    $start = '0';
    $limit = '25';
```

I need some help on implementing a way to paginate using my current PHP code above. How can I add on to what I have in my PHP code?

Comment: This is a problem that can no longer be reproduced because we don't have data to use.

Comment: just change $start to 25 on the next call...

Comment: @Fabricator please give an example.

Comment: I would go mysql way, but im only suggesting this if you know mysql. What i do is everytime a user visits your page they will get a random uniq id using PHP and stored as a cookie. Then using PHP you create a temporary mysql table using that id. You use this table to store all you XML data. Then you use this PHP pagination tutorial to list the data --- http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-create-pagination-in-php-and-mysql-with-ajax_315.html  --- mysql temporary tables are just temporary and get deleted automatically after a while. The whole process is super fast.

Comment: Thanks for the info but I doubt I will use mysql. the xml is loaded from indeed.com. I am not allowed to store it on my own server.

Comment: It would be great for someone to supply a full example. There is not a real good concise answer online for this. If it gets answered then it can be a post that gets referred back to when others ask it.

Answer (score 0):

`has_more` function returns true if there are 25 results in the xml

```
$start = 0;
do {
  $xml = simplexml_load_file(...$start...);
  // process $xml
  $start += 25;
} while(has_more($xml));
```

Comment: cool so once I have this, how do I display the pagination at the bottom of the page?

Comment: it produced a 500 error. `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function has_more()`

Comment: @Mike, you need to write `has_more` that examines `$xml` and check if there are 25 results.

Comment: don't have enough programming skills to figure that out.

Comment: @Mike, give this [xml parsing tutorial](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) a try

Comment: thanks I went through it and understand a few more things now. Still not sure how to incorporate what you gave me above and then have it paginate on the bottom of the page.

Comment: has_more($xml) doesn't need to count how many results there are. has_more should return true if  $xml->totalResults > $xml->pageNumber * $xml->limit